# Micorosoft Edge - Move window to second screen

Tags: javascript, window, microsoft-edge, multiple-monitors

I want via JavaScript in Micorsoft Edge to create a fullscreen-window and then move it to a second screen.

1. Create Window (easy obviously)
2. Make it fullscreen  (easy obviously)
3. Move it to second screen (idk)

**Hint:** The URL of both the exisiting window and the new window that should be moved is the same (1.: link.de/xy, 2.: link.de/xy/zz)

I've tried several proposed solutions but none of them worked correctly.
Has anyone an idea on how to accomplish this in the Edge-Browser?

Comment: I highly doubt you can move the window of Edge to another monitor. That breaks the sandbox of browser -> host machine that browsers employ.

Comment: I suppose this is not possible in practise. First, there's no way to diffrentiate primary and secondary monitors in JS, and usually moving the browser window is also not supported without giving a page extra privileges.

Comment: *"I've tried several proposed solutions but none of them worked correctly"* Like what? I'm surprised you could find any to try. Or is that there just so we don't think you didn't do research (which there's no sign of your having done).

Comment: @Teemu Do you know a solution if the page would have extra privileges? Every possible solution is appreciated... :)

Comment: `window.moveTo(x, y)` would move the browser window where ever you want, but detecting another monitor will still be a problem. Ex. I've three monitors, the middle-one is the primary, it has coordinates `0, 0` at the top-left corner, and `1920, 1200` at the bottom-right corner. The monitor at the left side has negative X, the monitor at the right-side has X > 1920 ... It's not possible to know, where the extra monitors are placed related to the primary monitor, or even in which monitor the browser window originally is placed.

Comment: Thanks @Teemu. Can you say anything about the point "giving a page extra privileges" on how to find a solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately, in case of Edge, I have no clue. But you have a pop-up window, which might already have the privilege to use `window.move`, if it was opened by `window.open`, not via a link.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Firefox, but Chrome & Edge don't do it.

It's obviously the wrapper around the Chromium engine they all use.

I use this bit of javascript to launch 2 full screens, one on each monitor. I save it as a shortcut on the desktop

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">

function fullwin() {
Win1=window.open("https://www.example1.com", "Display1","top=0, left=0, width=1920, height=1080, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes");

Win2=window.open("https://www.example2.com","Display2", "top=0, left=1921, width=1920, height=1080, scrollbars=no, resizable=yes"); 

window.opener=self;window.close();
}

</script>
</head>
<body onLoad='fullwin()'>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```